# Extrude Manifold making extra vertices

Tags: modeling, extrude

I want to extrude this face using Extrude Manifold tool

[image]

but when i do that , its leave the vertices that on the bottom face ;
[image]

so is there any thing to do to dissolve the vertices directly without any further to do?

Comment: Extruding, by definition, always creates new vertices, leaving the originals connected. If you just want to move the face, then select the face and press G to move it.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get rid of a random vertex in the middle of an edge.

Select the offending vert and double tap <kbd>G</kbd> to do a vertex slide.  Move it all the way over to where it is in the same position as one of the vertices on the end.  Enable x-ray view and box select both of the vertices and do a Mesh -> Merge -> By Distance.

Extrude Manifold doesn't automatically generate good topology, unfortunately.  You have several faces here with more than 4 verts even getting rid of those two extra vertices.

Comment: For quick ways, you can enable Auto Merge in the viewport tool settings, then with snapping enabled just move vertices over the ones which should stay. Or you can just select several vertices and press Ctrl+X